# How is dialogflow able to tell the source of text request like facebook or telegram?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to integrate my platform with a custom source on dialogflow using *apiai* package in NodeJs and I want my webhook to be able to pick out the source from the payload. Where do I need to set the source in the text request?

I am running apiai 4.0.3, node v12.3.1 (if that helps).

```
let request = client.textRequest(message, {
    sessionId: `${new Date().getTime()}`
});
```

I expect the source parameter of my webhook payload to be a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

After digging into apiai, and dialogflow's reference documentation, I found out that you could add

```js
{"requestSource": "facebook"}
```

or

```js
{"originalRequest":{
    "source": "facebook",
    "data":{ 
        //… 
    }
}
```

in your *textRequest* options.

You can find other query options in *query_request.js* and *text_request.js* files.

*query_requests.js*

```js
...

if ('requestSource' in application) {
    self.requestSource = application.requestSource;
}

if ('originalRequest' in options) {
    self.originalRequest = options.originalRequest;
}

...
```

Check out this link

https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query